# How to compare the row values of a column and update another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare, rows

I have a data frame column which is as shown below:

| items |
| --- |
| apple |
| apple |
| apple |
| mango |
| mango |
| cherry |

I am trying to generate a new column (result) using this. I compare the rows and if the previous row value is the same as the current row value, then the number in the result column remains the same, else it gets incremented.

| item | result |
| --- | --- |
| apple | 1 |
| apple | 1 |
| apple | 1 |
| mango | 2 |
| mango | 2 |
| cherry | 3 |

I can do this by converting the item column to a list, but want to know if there is a faster way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.shift()`, compare the columns and then do cumulative sum of the Boolean variables:

```
df["result"] = (df["items"] != df["items"].shift(1)).cumsum()
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    items  result
0   apple       1
1   apple       1
2   apple       1
3   mango       2
4   mango       2
5  cherry       3
```